# Using SSH or SCP within perl

Tags: perl, ssh, scp

I am using ssh within a perl script. I am getting belowe error during the script execution.
`stderr: Warning: Use of "-b-dor-2-rm" without parentheses is ambiguous at`

This is the error thrown by webserver as I am using perl-cgi.

Below is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

printf "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print <<HTML;
  <HTML>
   <HEAD>
    <TITLE>DataPower_Status</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
HTML

ssh root@sun-b-x-x-x <<'ENDSSH'
cd /tmp/dp/status
./getstatus
ENDSSH

scp -rp root@sun-x-x-x:/tmp/dp/status/DPlive_Status /opt/webserver7/https-sun-b-x-x-x-x/cgi-bin2/datapower/
chmod 777 DPlive_Status
open FILE, "DPlive_Status" or die "could not open filename";
while(<FILE>) {
    if ($_ =~ m/^Service/) {
         printf "<TR><TD><H4>$_</H4></TD></TR>\n";
    } else {
         printf "<TR><TD><p>$_</p></TD></TR>\n";
    }
}
close FILE;

print <<HTML;
</body></html>
HTML
```

Please let me know where am I committing a mistake? I think the way I am using SSH or SCP is  not correct.

Comment: You can't put a shell command directly in a perl script, you have to use `system()`.

Comment: Why don't you use a module like `Net::SSH2`?

Comment: I am new to perl programming, could you please help me in selecting one of these ( `system` or `Net::SSH2` ), and how can i implement this in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a shell command from Perl, you use `system()`:

```
system('ssh root@sun-b-x-x-x "cd /tmp/dp/status; ./getstatus"');
system('scp -rp root@sun-x-x-x:/tmp/dp/status/DPlive_Status /opt/webserver7/https-sun-b-x-x-x-x/cgi-bin2/datapower/');
chmod(0777, '/opt/webserver7/https-sun-b-x-x-x-x/cgi-bin2/datapower/DPlive_Status');
```

Comment: it is working like a charm. However, the chmod was not working, hence I have modified it like this:
`system('chmod 777 /opt/webserver7/https-sun-x-x-x-x/cgi-bin2/datapower/DPlive_Status ')`

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chmod.html

Comment: Did you remove the `0` from `0777`? That would break it, it needs to be octal, not decimal.

Comment: sorry, yes you were right, it is working fine.At the same time, 777 also worked fine.

Comment: The `chmod` shell command always treats its argument as octal. But in a Perl script, you're working with numeric values, not command arguments, so you have to make the radix explicit.